# tried using react-optimized-image but getting error

Tags: reactjs

have tried using react-optimized-image in reactjs.

have followed the required procedure as per - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-optimized-image

but getting below error.

```
  react-dom.development.js:16543 Uncaught Error: Babel plugin 'react-optimized-image/plugin' not 
  installed or this component could not be recognized by it.
      at Img (Img.js:119)
      at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:13380)
      at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:13820)
      at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:15863)
      at workLoop (react-dom.development.js:15902)
      at renderRoot (react-dom.development.js:15942)
      at performWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:16560)
      at performWork (react-dom.development.js:16482)
      at performSyncWork (react-dom.development.js:16454)
      at requestWork (react-dom.development.js:16354)
```

please advise...

Comment: Do you have a .bablerc file? can you post the full code?